# Get WebElements and For Look Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Why is the below code not working

```
@{expectedList} =    Create List          iphone X           Samsung Note 8    Nokia Edge    
${elements} =        Get WebElements      css:.card-title
Log To Console       ${elements}
@{actualList} =      Create List 1 2 3
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
    Append To List    ${actualList}      ${element.text}
    Log To Console    ${element.text}
END
```

${elements} list is empty
I was expecting 4 elements text.
I see the .card-title css in the site

Below is the screenshot
and this is the url of site
https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/shop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr3Nb.jpg)

Comment: I am trying to append a list by getting elements from the site